# Python Selenium .execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);") not scrolling down

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to open this page https://justjoin.it/warszawa/devops and then scroll to the bottom of the page.
I've tried in this way but unfortunately it doesn't work.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get(
    "https://justjoin.it/warszawa/devops")

close_popup = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/button'))).click()

time.sleep(3)
print('Time over!')

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try if `ActionChains` work for you. Sharing an example below. Use it as per your requirement.

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

last_element=driver.find_element_by_xpath("{{xpath of last element in the page}}")
a = ActionChains(driver)
a.move_to_element(last_element).perform()
```

Comment: As you can see on above page there is not last element unfortunatelly :(

Comment: Still you can scroll it till the element you want to be in focus. Just select xpath of the next element as `last_element`

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling goes on the wrong element. The page is not scrolled through window, but on a completely different element

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@style, 'will-change: transform')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTo(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight);", element)
```